# Symbol for potentially dirty ground

Tags: schematics, ground, symbol

I have a net which, although should be ground, could potentially be dirty and contain all sorts of minor noise. What is the correct way for me to denote this in my schematic?

Comment: You could add an inductor in series 1uH/m with ground, but unless you define the noise emitters symbolically, it's hard to relate.  It could be conducted or radiated noise.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I'm not worried about fixing it, I just want it to be visible that it could be dirty

Comment: Ground symbolically  means 0V  .  Add notes to verify with some other reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Surprisingly IEC symbols come close, at least for a "Clean" ground, see No. 5018:**

[image]

**For a "Dirty Ground" perhaps something like this would be close enough:**
[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NakUw.png